# Google Analytics view filter with two filter field

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm trying to set up a view filter with two conditions.

Include -> Campaign Source -> 23342

or

Include -> Request URL -> 3203

How can I set up a filter with two Filter Field?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set two different filter. In this way, if the condition of the first filter is respected, the hit will be filtered, otherwise if it is not respected, the hit will be blocked by the second. If no filter matches then the hit will be displayed in Google Analytics view.

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin you can create multiple Filters but they apply to one field at a time. Create one for the Campaign and one for the Request URI. Then apply them in sequence.